# Unity load scene issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

Scene is getting duplicated in hierarchy and switching between it. I am sharing all the screenshots here. kindly help me out if you can. And the buttons are also not working in the scene

Script

[image]

Buttons

[image]

Scenes

[image]

Hierarchy

[image]

Comment: In general please do not upload image of code. And avoid by all means ALL CAPS text

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the `mainMenu` has your script in it.

=> whenever your `mainMenu` scene is loaded

- `Start` is called
- which calls `SceneManager.LoadScene("mainScene");`

=> which ends up in an endless loop of over and over again loading the `mainMenu`